# Why does changing Bundlers installation directory cause Sorbet to fall over?

Tags: ruby, sorbet

For reasons to do with my CI setup I've needed to change the location where I install my Ruby gems from the default location to:  `bundle config set path 'vendor/bundle'`

However, as soon as I do so, Sorbet loses it's cool and throws out over 6,000 errors. Why would Sorbet be so sensitively dependent on where the gem is installed? (I clear all of the gems before switching location so it's very unlikely to be due to a clash of gem versions).

**Summary**

When gems are installed to:

```
/Users/my-home-directory/.rbenv/versions/2.7.5/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems
```

`bundle exec srb tc` works fine. But when gems are installed to:

```
/Users/my-home-directory/project-name/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.7.0/gems/
```

then running `bundle exec srb tc` generates thousands of errors.

Comment: Did you `bundle install --deployment`? Where does sorbet think the gems are, where are the rbi/rbs files, and is sorbet expecting rbi files for all those gems? Some actual error output and the steps to recreate it would be helpful.

Comment: Hi Todd - thanks for the qualifying questions - it actually all got solved by @dug's fix below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Sorbet attempts to typecheck the entire directory under `project-name`. Try adding the following line to `sorbet/config`:

```
--ignore=/vendor/bundle
```

(This should be automatically included in newer installs of sorbet that incorporate https://github.com/sorbet/sorbet/pull/3897 )

Comment: Brilliant - thank you @dug and for fixing it in Sorbet too. That did the job perfectly!